# Pytorch RNN always gives the same output for multivariate time series

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I have a time series data looking something like this:
[image]

I am trying to model this with a sequence to sequence RNN in pytorch. It trains well and I can see the loss going down. But on testing it gives the same out put irrespective of the input.

My Model:

```
class RNNModel(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, predictor_size, hidden_size, num_layers, dropout = 0.3, output_size=83):
    super(RNNModel, self).__init__()
    self.drop = nn.Dropout(dropout)
    self.rnn = nn.GRU(predictor_size, hidden_size, num_layers=num_layers, dropout = dropout)
    self.decoder = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
    self.init_weights()
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.num_layers = num_layers

def init_weights(self):
    initrange = 0.1
    self.decoder.bias.data.fill_(0)
    self.decoder.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)

def forward(self, input, hidden):
    output, hidden = self.rnn(input, hidden)
    output = self.drop(output)
    decoded = self.decoder(output.view(output.size(0) * output.size(1), output.size(2)))
    return decoded.view(output.size(0), output.size(1), decoded.size(1)), hidden

def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
    weight = next(self.parameters()).data
    return Variable(weight.new(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_size).zero_())
```

Train Method:

```
def train(data_source, lr):
    # turn on training mode that enables dropout

    model.train()
    total_loss = 0
    hidden = model.init_hidden(bs_train)
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = lr)

    for batch, i in enumerate(range(0, data_source.size(0) - 1, bptt_size)):

        data, targets = get_batch(data_source, i)

        # Starting each batch, we detach the hidden state from how it was previously produced
        # so that model doesen't ry to backprop to all the way start of the dataset
        # unrolling of the graph will go from the last iteration to the first iteration
        hidden = Variable(hidden.data)
        if cuda.is_available():
            hidden = hidden.cuda()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        output, hidden = model(data, hidden)
        loss = criterion(output, targets)
        loss.backward()

        # clip_grad_norm to prevent gradient explosion
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm(model.parameters(), clip)

        optimizer.step()
        total_loss += len(data) * loss.data
        # return accumulated loss for all the iterations
        return total_loss[0] / len(data_source)
```

Evaluation Method:

```
def evaluate(data_source):
    # turn on evaluation to disable dropout
    model.eval()
    model.train(False)
    total_loss = 0
    hidden = model.init_hidden(bs_valid)

    for i in range(0, data_source.size(0) - 1, bptt_size):
        data, targets = get_batch(data_source, i, evaluation = True)

        if cuda.is_available():
            hidden = hidden.cuda()

        output, hidden = model(data, hidden)
        total_loss += len(data) * criterion(output, targets).data
        hidden = Variable(hidden.data)

    return total_loss[0]/len(data_source)
```

Training Loop:

```
best_val_loss = None
best_epoch = 0
def run(epochs, lr):
    val_losses = []
    num_epochs = []
    global best_val_loss
    global best_epoch
    for epoch in range(0, epochs):
        train_loss = train(train_set, lr)
        val_loss = evaluate(test_set)
        num_epochs.append(epoch)
        val_losses.append(val_loss)
        print("Train Loss: ", train_loss, " Validation Loss: ", val_loss)

        if not best_val_loss or val_loss < best_val_loss:
            best_val_loss = val_loss
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), "./4.model.pth")
            best_epoch = epoch
    return num_epochs, val_losses
```

Loss with epochs:

[image]

Getting the output:

```
model = RNNModel(predictor_size, hidden_size, num_layers, dropout_pct, output_size)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("./4.model.pth"))

if cuda.is_available():
    model.cuda()

model.eval()
model.train(False)
hidden = model.init_hidden(1)
inp = torch.Tensor(var[105])
input = Variable(inp.contiguous().view(1,1,predictor_size), volatile=True)
if cuda.is_available():
    input.data = input.data.cuda()
output, hidden = model(input, hidden)
op = output.squeeze().data.cpu()
print(op)
```

Here I always get the same output irrespective of datapoint I give as input. Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: i'm not familiar with pytorch, so i'll only comment on a higher level. just based on the loss plot, seems like model is 'learning'.  If you evaluate the model right before you save the model, and after training is done, do you get the expected performance? if that is the case, then the problem lies in the inference part of the code, else problem is in the training  part of the code.

Comment: No I get the same result even if I test it just after training. I am not able to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If your learning rate is too large the model can train itself on the mean value overall. I don't see where you set `lr` above, can you try lowering it if that's possible?